# Oracle & PL/SQL Developer - Access predicates and Filter predicates no longer shown

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sql-execution-plan, plsqldeveloper

I'm using Allround Automation PL/SQL Developer with Oracle 10g, and today I've noticed that explain plans no longer display anything for Access Predicates or Filter Predicates. The only thing that's changed (that I know of) is that yesterday I tried using Oracle Enterprise Manager to explain a query plan, and after that PL/SQL Developer no longer populated these two columns.

I don't know if using OEM might have changed some setting that is now confusing PL/SQL Developer. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you

```
SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM dba_tables
 WHERE table_name = 'PLAN_TABLE'
```

I've seen many times where different GUIs try to be "helpful" and create the `PLAN_TABLE` in a local schema if it doesn't exist there without noticing that there is a synonym to a shared `PLAN_TABLE`.  And, being helpful GUIs, they tend to create the plan table with an older version of the table that may not support reporting on things like access and filter predicates.

If there is only one `PLAN_TABLE`, can you use the latest utlxplan.sql script from your install to re-create the `PLAN_TABLE` (or verify that you have the latest version of the table)?

Comment: I can select from this, for each row there is one of 4 valid schema names as `OWNER` (one of which is the one I'm working with) and table_name is always `PLAN_TABLE`... The last_analyzed date is yesterday morning, even though I've been running plans much more recently. Finally, I noticed that PL/SQL Developer shows a `PLAN_TABLE` under the database browser, and that it is owned by my schema, and does not have the Access/Filter predicates columns. Is it safe to drop this locally-owned `PLAN_TABLE` and hope that PL/SQL Dev will be smart enough to look at the shared table next time?

Comment: You should be able to safely drop your local `PLAN_TABLE` assuming that there is a public synonym to the shared `PLAN_TABLE`.  You could also re-create your local `PLAN_TABLE` using the utlxplan.sql script.

Comment: @Justin Cave: I tried running `select * from all_synonyms where table_name = 'PLAN_TABLE';` and nothing came back. Does this mean there's no public synonym? BTW, I don't have admin on this server, so I don't think I can recreate anything that's not inside my schema - but then again OEM shouldn't have been able to modify anything outside my schema either (it shouldn't have any extra permissions that PLSQL Developer had), so how did I get the full query plans before, if there's no public synonym?

Comment: @Frustrated - Yes, that means there is no public synonym.  So if you drop the local table, you may need to re-create it using the utlxplan.sql script.

Comment: @Justin Cave: Wait a minute - I may have found it. I ran `select *
 from all_synonyms
 where table_name like '%PLAN_TABLE%';` And found a table owned by `SYS` whose name is `PLAN_TABLE$` (note the `$` in the physical table's name) with a synonym named `PLAN_TABLE` owned by `PUBLIC`. I guess this is what I'm looking for? Now is it safe to drop the local `PLAN_TABLE`?

Comment: @Frustrated - Yes.  Sorry, I didn't notice your earlier query was based on the `TABLE_NAME` rather than the `SYNONYM_NAME`.

Comment: @Justin Cave: Ok, dropped the local `PLAN_TABLE` and now query plans come back with populated Access Predicates and Filter Predicates. Thanks!! :)